# numbers with two distinct prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For each set of k-digit numbers, has anyone bothered to find exactly the number
containing two distinct prime factors each with exponents greater than zero and
the sum of all such numbers for each set?  Thus one would seek for 2-digit numbers 10,12,14...96, 98, 99 and the sum of them when added.

Comment: No, I doubt anyone bothered

Comment: It would be an excellent way to test your new Chinese Petaflop machine.

Comment: You already looked in the OEIS and didn't find it?

Comment: $6, 3048, 242903$, no results in the OEIS. Mwhahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: "The Short One" needs a Chinese Petaflop machine to continue so he can put a J U M B O sequences into OEIS.